# Build Helper Maven Plugin not removing entire regular expression

Tags: maven, version, build-helper-maven-plugin

I'm using the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) with the [`regex-property`](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html) goal. I want to remove any qualifiers from a version, giving me a `project.releaseVersion` property.

Let's say my project is using version `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`. I can use the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>set-project-release-version</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>project.releaseVersion</name>
        <value>${project.version}</value>
        <regex>-SNAPSHOT</regex>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Sure enough, now `project.releaseVersion` now contains `1.2.3`. Nice.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with other non-release versions, such as `1.2.3-beta.4`. So to get the "release" version, I simply want to remove everything after the first `-`. In regular expression form, I should be able to match `-*` and replace it with nothing, removing the dash and everything after it, just like I did for `-SNAPSHOT`. So I tried this:

```
        <regex>-*</regex>
```

If I try that on `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`, it gives me `1.2.3SNAPSHOT`. It appears to match the regular expression, but only replaces the `-`, *not the entire match*.

Is this a bug, as it seems to be, or am I doing it wrong? And does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: You are familiar with regular expressions? `-*` is not correct cause it will not match `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`...apart from that `1.2.3-beta.4` is a release version. I would suggest to try something this. `-SNAPSHOT` furthermore the question is: Why do you need that? I have checked the output via `-X` it works as expected? If you like to have the `1.2.3` of `1.2.3-beta.4` you have to use `-.*` instead...

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with regular expressions. I think I must have had a brain hiccup, because I was thinking in glob mode. I'll try `-.*` and see how that works.

Comment: @khmarbaise, Can you provide me a reference that `1.2.3-beta.4` is a release version? According to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) (which is what I'm trying to follow), any version with a hyphen and things following it is considered a "pre-release" version: "A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version."

Comment: @khmarbaise that indeed fixed my problem; I needed to use the regex `-.*` instead of the glob-like expression `-*`. Would you like to provide that in an answer so that I can mark it as correct? Otherwise, I'll provide a separate answer myself, but you're the one who pointed it out.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking of just deleting this question. As it was predicated on a blatant mistake (brain hiccup not withstanding), it may just provide more clutter than help.